# Is there a comprehensive list of all space probes ever launched?

Tags: probe, spacecraft, history, future-missions, reference-request

I'm working on a project and I was wondering if there is a comprehensive archive or a database available out there of all of the spacecrafts and human made probes that were ever launched into space (specially on missions to other celestial bodies than Earth, such as the sun, the inner and outer planets, planet's moons and asteroids) including USSR, ESA, JAXA etc. missions?

What about future missions?

Comment: the book [Space Probes: 50 Years of Exploration from Luna 1 to New Horizons, by Philippe Séguéla](http://www.amazon.de/Space-Probes-Years-Exploration-Horizons/dp/1554079446/) has such a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you mean with *comprehensive*, but [Wikipedia's List of Solar System probes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Solar_System_probes) seems fairly up to date (date for [InSight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InSight) is still 2016 and it has [recently been announced](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=4805) that the launch date slipped to no earlier than May 2018) and also includes *confirmed future probes* (subject to interpretation) and cancelled missions.

---

You should be able to also find infographics showing our Solar system exploration endeavors, but while visually appealing, unless they present past missions only and you pay attention to when they were created, those obviously won't age so gracefully as some community edited list. You could find some at [JPL Infographics](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/infographics/index.php), [Space.com Infographics](http://www.space.com/infographics/), or in our [Collection of space exploration related infographics](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/472/collection-of-space-exploration-related-infographics) on Space Exploration Meta (contributions welcome). For example, here's [JPL Mission Paths](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/infographics/infographic.view.php?id=11049):

[image]

I realize that infographics aren't really what you asked for, but since you mention that you're working on a project, perhaps some such visualizations wouldn't go amiss towards building awareness on the topic. Maybe for some poster session. ;)